# can 1 ADFS support multiple org?

Tags: single-sign-on

Hi I have ADFS setup for 1 of my org and its working fine, now i would like to add another org to the same ADFS server, can it be done?

As I got told that only 1 org can be setup in ADFS server as it uses 'POST' binding type. For each 'binding' type, there can only be one end point web address.

Is that so?

Thanks.

Comment: Suggest that when you use acronyms like ADFS that you [introduce](http://iconlogic.blogs.com/weblog/2010/09/writing-grammar-introducing-an-acronym.html) them or make them a link to more detail as the meaning may be obvious to you but often will not be to others.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. I once set up a half-dozen sandboxes on a single AD FS instance. Simply go into each instance, download the SAML XML file, and import it into AD FS under Relying Parties. You can also configure AD FS to allow users to choose which service to log into when using IdP-initiated logins.

Also, see my handy-dandy [AD FS Guide](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/56197/how-do-i-configure-ad-fs-3-0-to-support-salesforce-sso-especially-with-salesfor) I posted for common gotchas. Simply repeat the steps for each instance you want to be able to login to from AD FS. To support SP-initiated bindings, each instance should have My Domain enabled and SSO enabled.

Comment: hi, doesnt matter if we use 'POST' binding type in ADFS? I was told that we can have only 1 'POST' binding type in the ADFS server hence we cant add more Salesforce instance to the same ADFS server

Comment: @user2074703 From what I read, you should be using the redirect model, because it works better with mobile devices (iPhone, if I recall). I didn't try using POST, but I can definitely tell you I had five or six instances on a single ADFS server. I don't have a Windows Server I can play with any more,  so I'm only going to be of limited use here.