# My Org SSO refers me to home page, no deep linking

Tags: single-sign-on

In my company we set an SSO for salesforce, works good 
Yet - when user clicks a link he is always being directed to the Home page (or his default tab) if he is not already connected to SF.

Can you please suggest a way how to implement it properly?

Comment: If you're using AD FS, also check out my [Q&A](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/56197/how-do-i-configure-ad-fs-3-0-to-support-salesforce-sso-especially-with-salesfor) for various things that tripped me up during implementation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most comprehensive documentation is going to be the [Single Sign On Implementation Guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/206/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_single_sign_on.pdf).

From your description it sounds like your IdP is not passing the `RelayState` parameter back through correctly during the redirects that happen during the SSO process. This parameter contains the URL that the user initially requested before they were sent to the IdP for authentication.