# How do you replace Related Lists (Classic) to get past some platform limitations? (such as only 10 fields displayed)

Tags: visualforce, related-list

I'm frustrated that Related Lists can only have 10 fields.  And that they always have the "edit/del" commands as links instead of buttons.

Related Lists have quite a few behaviours that can't be customised without code.

Comment: Congrats. Is there a question or and answer somewhere?

Comment: I think you might want to post that on your blog rather than on different forums

Comment: This is a Q&A forum. In order to post content like this, the question should contain a question (basically, explain the problem that you had), and the answer should contain the entirety of the solution you used to solve the problem (the link is a good idea, but must not be the entire question or answer). See [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/56197) of an example of how to do that. Also, see [ask] and [answer].

Answer (score 0):

I did some development to get past some of the limitations of the Related List.  Here's my post on developer.salesforce.com:

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=9060G000000MUYqQAO

Hopefully this will help others out who are looking for a way to solve a similar problem.