# Generic SSO/ADFS question

Tags: single-sign-on, delegated-authentication, federated-authentication

My customer( a charity org) wants to implement SSO. 
They are using LDAP with Active Directory(AD) for authentication for other applications.

They want Salesforce SSO integrated with LDAP.

However, can I recommend the customer to use federation authentication instead of delegation(LDAP) method?

The reason being it is straightforward to implement and less effort(no creating Web service with wsdl, getting delegation SSO activated by Salesforce etc).

So, even if they have an AD using LDAP for authentication, can Salesforce SSO work using federation method?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Federated Authentication. As long as the user is able to connect to the service on their device, they will be able to use this feature. You can refer to my [self Q&A on how to implement AD FS SSO](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/56197/2984).

Comment: @sdfcfox Great. Thanks a lot. The post also clarifies another question I had regarding what happens when AD server goes down and how users(or at-least admins) can log into the system.